# How to stop (or hide) process 'python' showing up in dock in MacOS with Anaconda Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, spyder

I am using Spyder with Anaconda Launcher.

I was working on some machine learning models and when drawing graphs, I used `X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.00000001)`
Now the problem is that `0.00000001` takes a LOT of time to execute. Ideally people don't exceed `0.001`.

Because of this, there is one process called "python" always showing up in the dock. If I force quit it, the kernel in Spyder dies and restarts and it instantly shows up in the dock again.

[The python process icon in the dock looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCJrU.png)

I tried googling a lot, checking out answers in stackoverflow but none helped. I also tried completely removing anaconda from my mac, deleting the anaconda folder from the Users folder, then restarting the mac and then reinstalling it. Nothing seems to work! And it is really annoying to see that white icon in the dock.

So can anyone help me get rid of that white `python` process icon from the dock?

EDIT: I seem to have found the problem. Whenever I try to plot a graph using matplotlib, it used to appear in the console but the process icon used to not appear. To make the graph appear in a separate window, I go to Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics and select Automatic under 'Graphics Backend'. When I do this, this annoying icon appears again! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think that's not possible, sorry. Spyder consoles create a separate Python process to run your code on it, which (I think) is the `python` entry you're seeing in your dock. This is necessary to not block the Spyder interface (and you can keep using our Editor, for example) while a long computation is run in the console.

Comment: The problem occurs only when I choose to make the graphs appear in a different window. Please read my edit on the question. And if possible, can you please check on that?

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. Then the right explanation is that the *Automatic* backend creates a thread to be able to show graphs in a separate window. And that thread is shown as `python` in your dock. This is necessary to not block the console while you generate the plot, and it's not controlled by Spyder. It's the way Matplotlib works inside IPython.

Comment: Does it happen to you too? I've used this on my friend's laptop which runs Windows and this doesn't happen. I haven't tried it out on any other Mac though.

Comment: It only happens in macOS, sorry.